# Integrate Applovin to Cocos2d-x iOS app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocos2d-x, applovin

I want to integrate Applovin SDK to my Cocos2d-x iOS app, but the delegate doesn't work.

```
[ALInterstitialAd shared].adDisplayDelegate = self;  << Error: Use of undeclared identifier 'self'
[ALInterstitialAd showOver:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]];
```

OR

```
objClass *obj1 = [objClass alloc];
[ALInterstitialAd shared].adDisplayDelegate = obj1;  << Error: assigning 'id<ALAdDisplayDelegate>' from incompatibile type "objClass *"
```

OR

```
init: objClass* obj1 = [[objClass alloc] init];
[ALInterstitialAd shared].adDisplayDelegate = obj1;  << Error: assigning 'id<ALAdDisplayDelegate>' from incompatibile type "objClass *"
```

How to fix this?
I want to capture those listener events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just resolved this issue, but I'm working with pure Object-C in Xcode. I was getting error until I added delegate methods: ALAdDisplayDelegate, ALAdLoadDelegate, ALAdUpdateObserver, ALAdVideoPlaybackDelegate

.h

```
#import "ALInterstitialAd.h"

@interface VSGalleryViewController : UIViewController <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, ALAdDisplayDelegate, ALAdLoadDelegate, ALAdUpdateObserver, ALAdVideoPlaybackDelegate>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Adding "ALAdDisplayDelegate" to the @interface of .h file did fix the issue, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

If this code is in a Objective-C class but in a class method (denoted with the leading `+`) then self will also be unavailable. Use the code in an instance method (denoted with a leading `-`) instead.

In C++ code there is no `self` keyword. Instead use the `this` pointer. Though in this case that probably won't work since the API is in Objective-C - therefore the delegate likely needs to be an Objective-C object (`id`).

In case you are writing C++ code you would have to create a Objective-C wrapper class that implements the protocol (if any) that is required for the adDisplayDelegate to work.

Comment: I tried "objClass *obj1 = [objClass alloc];", check edited question. But still not working.

Comment: Just seeing this, in ObjC you must call init: objClass* obj1 = [[objClass alloc] init];
Besides that, this class must implement the ALAdDisplayDelegate protocol.

Comment: Even I wrote  init: objClass* obj1 = [[objClass alloc] init];
        [ALInterstitialAd shared].adDisplayDelegate = obj1;  It still show the same error.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D is it possible to control the full screen mode of ads from applovin ?